# Prove that there is some $p\in S^1$ for which the angle between $p$ and $h(p)\in S^1$ is $90^{\circ}$.

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Studying for a test I encountered this next question:

Let $S^1$ be the unit circle, $h:S^1\to S^1$ a continuous function which is homotopic to the constant function.

1) Prove that there is some $p\in S^1$ for which the angle between $p$ and $h(p)\in S^1$ is $90^{\circ}$.

2) (**my own question**) For what angles ($\theta\in[0,2\pi]$) does $p$ exist?

### *My thoughts:*

- I tried constructing some function which would help when using    Brouwer fixed-point theorem, no luck so far.
- There are continuous functions that does not meet the criteria, e.g $f(z)=ze^{i}$, but they are not homotopic to the constant function since they complete a full circle, so I assume that the composition $h\circ g:[0,1]\to S^1$ for $g:[0,2\pi]\to S^1, g(t)=e^{ti}$ does not complete a circle (am I right?) but I cannot see how I can put any boundary on the degree between a point and its image...

Comment: Question 2 is very illuminating. Indeed, such points exist for all $\theta $. To know this without proof just imagine the graph of the function $[0,2\pi)\ni x\mapsto x +\theta \mod 2\pi $. Any other function on $[0,2\pi) $ crosses this function unless it makes a 'full turn', in which case it wouldn't be homotopic to the constants anymore

Comment: h can "complete the full circle" any finite number of times, as long as it comes back again. I.e.  if $\theta$ is the angle between h(g((0)) and h(g(t)) then as t varies from 0 to 1, $\theta$ can go beyond $\pm{2\pi}$ as long as it finishes back at 0. Meanwhile, the angle between g(0) and g(t) goes from 0 to $2\pi$. Now just apply the Intermediate Value Theorem. (Bananach is essentially suggesting the same.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brouwer's fixed point is a great tool. If $h\colon S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is null-homopotic, then you can expand it to $H\colon B^2 \rightarrow S^1$ with $H\vert_{S^1} = h$. By Brouwer's fixed point THM, that $H$ has a fixed point $x\in B^2$ such that $H(x_0) = x_0\in S^1$, so $x_0$ is infact on the circle. We have,
$$1=\langle H(x_0) ,x_0 \rangle=\langle h(x_0),x_0\rangle$$

If this helped you, then you should stop reading here and figure out how to get a negative sign for that function $x\mapsto \langle h(x),x\rangle$.

Consider $R\circ h$ with $R$ a rotation by $\pi$ (it is linear, thus continuous). This $R\circ h$ is obviouslly still null-homotpic, and we again obtain another $x^-$ such that $R\circ h(x^-) = x^-$. Inverting this, we have $$h(x^-)=R^{-1}\circ R\circ h(x^-)=R^{-1}(x^-)=-x^-$$ (i'm hope this isn't too confusing). Anyways:
$$-1=\langle -x^- ,x^- \rangle =\langle h(x^-),x^-\rangle$$

Comment: Why the downvote? In my opinion, this is a very good answer :)

Comment: Let's say $R$ is a rotation by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ then $R\circ h$ is still homotopic to a constant, same logic then - leads to $R \circ h (x)=x$ meaning $h(x)=R^{-1}(x)$ and that is what we wanted, am I correct?

Comment: @Daniel I actually like what you suggest better. I would like to add something, you probably notice (as I did, when studying this) that the use of the above techniques repeat over and over again. I would suggest you to view them in a more general context: (i) The use of fixed point theorems (you should find out what is the more general form of this Brouwer's THM). (ii) If $h\colon X \rightarrow Y$ is null-homotpic then $h$ can be expanded to the topological cone $CX$ (find out what is null-homotopy in this wider content of topological spaces).

Comment: @Daniel, I just noticed, your more elegant arguement answers your second question with no further effort.